# Try to add new validation rule in reactjs material

Tags: forms, reactjs, validation, material-ui

I was trying to add new validation rule. I am using react-material 1.0

Here is the code by which I add new rule but got error

```
ValidatorForm.addValidationRule('isCanRequired', (value) => {
        if(this.state.canSameAccount){
          if(value==null || value==="" || value===undefined)
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Here is the field in which I add this new rule

```
<TextValidator fullWidth name="canAddress1" value={this.state.canAddress1}
                          validators={['isCanRequired']} errorMessages={['Please enter your street address 1']}
                          label="Enter Street Address 1*" onChange={this.handleChange('canAddress1')} />
```

Here is the error screenshot when I click on submit button

[image: Error]

Comment: hi! in which method of the components life cycle do you add validation rule ? I have added this in the `componentWillMount` and got your code working.

Comment: I am adding in componentWillMount but code is not working

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer 
Because of beta version of react-material-ui-form-validator. Need to change the package of `ValidatorForm`

```
import {ValidatorForm} from 'react-material-ui-form-validator'
```